# Indenting part numbers to the left

Tags: table-of-contents, indentation

When I produce a table of contents in my latex document which is of the report type, with just the plain `\tableofcontents` command, I see the part numbers and chapter numbers are in the same column. I would like the part numbers to be indented more to the left.

How do I achieve this?

Currently, this is the output I am getting

[image]

Comment: Please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) for this purpose.  There are going to be different answers, depending on the class you are using, and possibly the packages.

Comment: Or have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/464943/37907

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can patch how `\part` writes the part number in the `.toc` file:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@part}
  {\thepart\hspace{1em}}
  {\inmargin{\thepart}}
  {}{}
\makeatother
\newrobustcmd{\inmargin}[1]{%
  \makebox[0pt][r]{\makebox[2em][l]{#1}}%
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{Overview}

\chapter{Description of Problems}

\chapter{Installation and Use}

\part{Another one}

\chapter{Whatever}

\end{document}
```

Here 2em is the width of the box with the part number. Adjust it to suit your needs.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When using `memoir` document class, you can do this:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\renewcommand{\cftpartpresnum}{\hskip-15pt}
\renewcommand{\cftpartaftersnumb}{\hskip-15pt}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{text}

\chapter{test2}

\chapter{test3}

\end{document}
```

[image: Left-shifted part number and title]

The first specifies something before the part number, while the second specifies something after the part number, immediately before the part name/title.

If you prefer to indent (i.e. shift right), you will want the number(s) to be positive, rather than negative.