# How to adjust font size of "parts" in table of contents

Tags: fonts, fontsize

In the table of contents that is being generated with the following code
notice that the size of the fonts of part, chapter, section are nearly the same, and also of the same family.

How can I adjust the font-type and size of part, to be different from that of chapter and section.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\title{My Report}
\author{A.U. Thor}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
 \tableofcontents
\part{Part 1}
\chapter{Introduction}
\section{Foo}
\section{Bar}
\blindtext
\chapter{An Overview}
\section{Fiddle}
\section{DeeDee}
\blindtext

\part{Part 2}
\chapter{Introduction}
\section{TweedleDum}
\section{TweedleDee}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: One of the usual suspects to customize the visual appearance of the toc would be `tocloft`.

Comment: A switch to a KOMA-class would take care of the problem from a few minutes earlier and also make this question much easier to answer. And probably also that *indent part number to the left* question.

Comment: Another simple possibility is `titletoc` , which comes with package `titlesec`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the `tocloft` package:

```
\documentclass{book} % or whatever
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftpartfont}{\Huge\itshape} % Part title in Huge Italic font
\begin{document}
\part{A Part}
\chapter{A Chapter}
\end{document}
```

You may want to change the Part's pagenumber to match by, for example:

```
\renewcommand{\cftpartpagefont}{\Huge\itshape}
```

but maybe not.

Read the manual (`> texdoc tocloft`) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

With a KOMA-script class, you would have a set of tools that can get what you want easily.

[image: smilingbuddhaToc]

```
\documentclass[12pt,egregdoesnotlikesansseriftitles]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\title{My Report}
\author{A.U. Thor}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[tocindent=-1em,tocentryformat=\sffamily\bfseries,tocpagenumberformat=\tiny]{part}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
 \tableofcontents
\part{Wombats}
\chapter{Introduction}
\section{Foo}
\section{Bar}
\blindtext
\chapter{An Overview}
\section{Fiddle}
\section{DeeDee}
\blindtext

\part{Capybaras}
\chapter{Introduction}
\section{TweedleDum}
\section{TweedleDee}

\end{document}
```

Note: The font of the part entry changed, the font of the pagenumber has changed differently, the part entry is indented and the page number was not reset after the title page. Three questions answered in one.